# card flip effect with Five3D and TweenMax/TweenLite

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d

I want to create a card flip effect where I have a card front image, and a card back image. Is there a way to do it so that I have two images in 3d space, one in front of the other, and just rotate their container? If not, how can I achieve this? Also, while i'm using Five3D, i can probably figure out how to convert it if anyone has an example in another library such as papervision3D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soulwire has a neat solution which extends Sprite. It just adds a "front" and "back" properties (can be any DisplayObject) and handles everything else automatically. Nice if you just need simple two sided planes, but don't want to get elbow deep into a 3D framework.

http://blog.soulwire.co.uk/code/open-source/two-sided-planes-in-flash-player-10

Comment: after some minor modification, I was able to get this to work. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need 3d and can use flash10, I suggest going with [SideDetector](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=468).

With ppv3d, you could create 2 [planes](http://papervision3d.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/as3/trunk/docs/org/papervision3d/objects/primitives/Plane.html) with a [one-sided texture](http://papervision3d.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/as3/trunk/docs/org/papervision3d/core/proto/MaterialObject3D.html#doubleSided), flip one and stuff them into a [group](http://papervision3d.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/as3/trunk/docs/index.html). I'd assume you can do something like that with Five3D as well.

Comment: i need 3d, cause i'm trying to flip the card as i'm moving it along the z axis. so I guess I'll try to find Five3D's equivalent to planes and go from there

Comment: @LordZardeck: In FlashPlayer 10, every `DisplayObject` can be [rotated along along the z-axis](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#rotationZ)

Comment: Oh, i've tried rotating it, but it doesn't put the back image in front. it more or less just flips the images

Comment: @LordZardeck: That's what the SideDetector I mentioned above does. You can also use Wintamute's suggestion, which already encapsulates this in a single class.

Comment: would you be able to place that inside a sprite3d class to achieve manipulation in 3d space?

Comment: @LordZardeck: Again, why do you need 3d? If all you want is to flip cards, you don't need a full 3d engine, if you use flash player 10 3d transformations instead.

Comment: I need to be able to place cards in the distance on a 3d table and things like that

Comment: @LordZardeck: Still no problem. Use the `z`-property or just scale them to create a spatial effect. You shouldn't use a 3d-engine unless you need to. As long as you can do it with flash 3d transformations, your swf will be smaller and run at a higher framerate.

Comment: +1 your idea about not needing 3d engine was correct. I tried placing the paper sprite in a Sprite3D, but I couldn't rotate the Sprite3D then. So after removing the 3d engine, and trying everything with just flash's api, it all worked the way I wanted. Thanks!